# Creating a new sheet programmatically using Office JS

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-addins

Is there an API which can help to create a new sheet programmatically through an Excel Add In using Excel JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `add` method on the `WorksheetCollection` object:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetcollection#addname-string

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael for a quick response!